# text display inside block <a> with image - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page like below;

```
<style type="text/css">
#test a{
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
</style>

<div id="test">
    <a>text text text<img src="image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

I am getting the result like;

[image: current result]

But I want something like;

[image: result required]

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/nPSBL/)** is the fiddle

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `vertical-align:top` to the image

```
#test img{vertical-align:top;}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPSBL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can define `#test img {vertical-align:top;}`

As like this

**css**

```
#test a{
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#test img{vertical-align:top;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <a>text text text<img src="http://i.imgur.com/VlyB1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/nPSBL/2/
​

Answer (score -1):

try adding to the CSS:

```
#test a {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: it still works. it aligns everything inside the link to top. http://jsfiddle.net/BEKYB/

Comment: well, making it accidently work in some quirky browser doesn't count. Try `vertical-align:middle` on your example... The correct usage is on the inline-element. Plz correct that.